# New UI of Dev Center, where find option "Authenticating your service"?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-dev-center

I'm looking for button "Authenticating your service" via [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465407), and I can't find something similar on Microsoft Dev Center. I want to get a "client secret", where I can find it on Dev Center? [image: Where to find it??]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the app name, go to `App management`> `WNS/MPNS`> click `Live Service site`.

Then you enter the your application registration portal page and can get the `Application Secrets` as your `client secret`:

[image]